# Integrate Appcelerator Cloud Services to a custom website made with ASP.NET

Tags: android, asp.net, titanium

I'm really new to mobile world, so I'd like to get some opinion from experienced people.
After several days searching over the internet, I'm wondering if it's possible
integrate Appcelerator Cloud Services to a custom website made with ASP.NET, for example. 
Although my mobile application, built with Titanium, it's linked to ACS, and works fine, I don't know if
it's possible to manage data stored in ACS from a custom website. To clarify, in one point there is my mobile application
talks to a webserver (ACS, for example) and other point there is a website, to manage the data stored in ACS.
What do you think, someone achieved this? 
Or is it preferable to write a webserver from the scratch, store my data in somewhere, and forget about ACS?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator says

> Appcelerator Cloud Services (ACS) is a Mobile Backend as a Service
>   (MBaaS), offering a fast and easy way to build connected mobile apps.
>   Choose from a library of services such as push notification, status
>   updates, photo storage, and social integration, or create your own
>   custom cloud services.

Here in this page - [Getting Started: Using the Javascript SDK](http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/javascript#) - you can see how we can use javascript SDK which lets you access the Appcelerator Cloud Services server through some simple to use JavaScript calls. You can use this to develop web-based app.

Comment: @TiagoTecchio Yes I do, I am a titanium developer

Answer (score 0):

ACS has a REST API which you can access through anything that supports xhr (which .NET does).  For instance, to create a new user in ACS, you use the following link:

https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/create.json?key=YOUR APP APP KEY?email=john.smith@company.com&role=teacher

There are other properties you can tag onto the querystring to create a new user from a REST call.  They have a complete API using REST.  It's all documented. You can even send push notifications to devices from your custom website using the REST API!  It's pretty cool.

http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/users/create#rest

Good luck!